# Selecting specific rows SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want a query to select 2 rows for every NumberId from the table  that occur without being interrupted by another NumberId, and same for another NumberId and so on

```
ID      Name         NumberId
---------------------------
1       Abc          1
2       bcd          1
3       cde          1
4       def          2
5       efg          2
6       fgh          2
7       ghij         2 
8       defg         1
9       efgj         1
10      fghi         1
11      ghij         1
```

I want to select 2 rows from `NumberId 1`  and 2 rows from `NumberId 2`  and again 2 rows from `NumberId 1`

Comment: Don't understand the question! Give us some DDL, some DML, some sample data, the answer you require and the logic you used to arrive at that answer. Take a look  [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) and [here](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example). Take the tour and vist the help centre  - help us to help you! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: And then when you still have rows with 1 left and no rows left with 2, what do you do?

Comment: I wanted pair of rows for every consecutive NumberId, Remaining rows doesn't matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
--set up demo data
declare @T table (id int, name varchar(10), NumberId int)
insert into @T(id, name, NumberId) values
(1,'Abc',1),
(2,'bcd',1),
(3,'cde',1),
(4,'def',2),
(5,'efg',2),
(6,'fgh',2),
(7,'ghij',2), 
(8,'defg',1),
(9,'efgj',1),
(10,'fghi',1),
(11,'ghij',1 )
;
```

---

I used a common table expression to create groupings of consecutive NumberId's

--Create a grouping for consecutive values called grp

```
;WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY Numberid ORDER BY [id]
                ), [id]) AS grp
    FROM @T
    )
    select * from _cte
```

---

```
| id | name | NumberId | grp                     |
|----|------|----------|-------------------------|
| 1  | Abc  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 2  | bcd  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 3  | cde  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 4  | def  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 5  | efg  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 6  | fgh  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 7  | ghij | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 |
| 8  | defg | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 9  | efgj | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 10 | fghi | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 |
| 11 | ghij | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 |
```

---

Then, I used another common table expression to add a row_number to each row in the above result

---

```
;WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY Numberid ORDER BY [id]
                ), [id]) AS grp
    FROM @T
    )
    select * from _cte order by id
    ,AddedRn    --add a row number for each entry in the group
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id
            ) AS rn
    FROM _cte
    )
```

---

```
| id | name | NumberId | grp                     | rn |
|----|------|----------|-------------------------|----|
| 1  | Abc  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1  |
| 2  | bcd  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2  |
| 3  | cde  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 3  |
| 4  | def  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 1  |
| 5  | efg  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 2  |
| 6  | fgh  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 3  |
| 7  | ghij | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 4  |
| 8  | defg | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 1  |
| 9  | efgj | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2  |
| 10 | fghi | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 3  |
| 11 | ghij | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 4  |
```

---

Now put it all together and only select rows where `rn` in (1,2)

---

```
--set up demo data
declare @T table (id int, name varchar(10), NumberId int)
insert into @T(id, name, NumberId) values
(1,'Abc',1),
(2,'bcd',1),
(3,'cde',1),
(4,'def',2),
(5,'efg',2),
(6,'fgh',2),
(7,'ghij',2), 
(8,'defg',1),
(9,'efgj',1),
(10,'fghi',1),
(11,'ghij',1 )
;

--Create a grouping for consecutive values called grp
WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,DATEADD(DAY, - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY Numberid ORDER BY [id]
                ), [id]) AS grp
    FROM @T
    )
    ,AddedRn    --add a row number for each entry in the group
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY id
            ) AS rn
    FROM _cte
    )
--Select only the rows with rn in (1,2)
SELECT *    
FROM AddedRn
WHERE rn IN (1,2)
ORDER BY id
```

---

```
| id | name | NumberId | grp                     | rn |
|----|------|----------|-------------------------|----|
| 1  | Abc  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1  |
| 2  | bcd  | 1        | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2  |
| 4  | def  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 1  |
| 5  | efg  | 2        | 1900-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 2  |
| 8  | defg | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 1  |
| 9  | efgj | 1        | 1900-01-05 00:00:00.000 | 2  |
```

Comment: Why did you choose to use dates to form the `grp` column?

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy, I wasn't sure whether i explained clearly or not but you did it right. Thanks :) Appreciated

Comment: @MichaelGreen - Honestly Michael, literally no other reason other than it was the first example that I could find on the Internet (that worked) to do what I was trying to do.  ;)

Comment: I guessed as much! Using dates limits the table to the number of days since the epoch. While this is in the millions it may still be insufficient in some scenarios. Refactoring to use, say, the maximum integer value may be more applicable for some implementations.